# Possible in Geopandas to calculate number of entities that can fit into a given shapefile?

Tags: geopandas

I'll preface this question with the caveat that I am a complete newbie to GIS / spatial calculations. Apologies if this is obvious.

Is it possible (easy? hard?) with GeoPandas to do the following...

Given:

1. A shapefile with "boxes" covering specific areas of a map
2. "Line" entities designated by lat/lng coordinates of the top and bottom of the line
3. A specified minimum horizontal distance between lines

Calculate:
The number of additional lines that can fit into the box?

As an example:

[image]

Given the existing orange lines in the blue box, how many additional lines can fit into the blue box (i.e. in the green area) if I specify the orange lines need at least "x" space between them?

In this case, if the spacing is kept the same, the answer might be something like 5 additional lines.

Hopefully, this is sufficient information to provide an answer, if not I can give additional details... Not sure what information needs to be specified given my lack of background in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, geopandas stores the geometries in the "geometry" column as shapely geometries. So after loading the shapefile using geopandas, you can iterate over the rows and use the functionalities in the shapely library to check the lines being in the boxes: [shapely documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)

In the simple example below I use the box function of shapely to create a box: [shapely.box](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.box). Then, in a loop, [linestings](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#collections) are created and checked whether they are contained by the box using the "contains"  [binary predicate](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#binary-predicates)

```
import shapely

box = shapely.box(0, 0, 100, 100)
nb_lines = 0
for x in range(30, 200, 10):
    line = shapely.LineString([(x, 10), (x, 90)])
    if box.contains(line):
        nb_lines += 1
    else:
        break

print(f"nb_lines: {nb_lines}")
```

Output:

```
7
```

Comment: Could you maybe add a code snippet as an example?

Comment: I added some sample code...